# Missing fields after converting CSV to JSON with ConvertRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

I have CSV looks like:

```
Date,Media Source,Campaign,Impressions,Clicks,CTR,Installs
2021-08-07,googleadwords_int,Android_UAC,N/A,N/A,N/A,258
2021-08-07,yandexdirect_int,Android_MK,N/A,301,N/A,6
```

I'm trying to convert this CSV to JSON, but most of fields are missing.
Actual result:

```json
[
  {
    "Date": "2021-08-07",
    "Media Source": "googleadwords_int",
    "Campaign": "Android_UAC"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-08-07",
    "Media Source": "yandexdirect_int",
    "Campaign": "Android_MK"
  }
]
```

Expected:

```json
[
  {
    "Date": "2021-08-07",
    "Media Source": "googleadwords_int",
    "Campaign": "Android_UAC",
    "Impressions": null,
    "Clicks": null,
    "CTR": null,
    "Installs": 258
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-08-07",
    "Media Source": "yandexdirect_int",
    "Campaign": "Android_MK",
    "Impressions": null,
    "Clicks": 301,
    "CTR": null,
    "Installs": 6
  }
]
```

CSVReader config:
[image: csv]

I guess it's because I set "N/A" as Null string. But I want to write "N/A" in fields as null. How to fix it?

Comment: From this configuration at converter, you may not achieve this and I think you should replace the N/A column value with null before passing to this converter.

Comment: I though that option "Null String" should replace "N/A" with null in converter.

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/index.html. Have a look at Null String description in this link, the value configured for Null String will be considered as null while reading the record but does not replace it.

Comment: Maybe if you are using jsonrecordsetwriter in converter then try changing this property Suppress Null Values once: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonRecordSetWriter/index.html

Comment: Fixed it with `UpdateRecord` and `RecordPath`.